# Only print output after finding pattern

Tags: echo, printf

There's a script (let's call it `echoer`) that prints to screen a bunch of information. I'd like to be able to only see lines after a pattern is found.

I imagine the usage of a solution to look something like

```
echoer | solution_command <pattern>
```

Ideally `pattern` would be a regular expression, but hard value strings would be enough for me.

Comment: So pattern can be multiple strings?

Comment: A glob? Do you mean a regular expression? Globs only make sense for file name expansions.

Comment: @Inian I'm not sure I understand the question. Do you mean to ask if I want this to work with disjunctions?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

AWK can do this with pattern ranges, which allows the use of any regular expression:

```
echoer | awk '/pattern/,0'
```

will print `echoer`’s output starting with the first line matching `pattern`.

AWK is pattern-based, and is typically used with a “if this pattern matches, do this” type of approach. “This pattern” can be a range of patterns, defined as “when this pattern matches, start doing this, until this other pattern matches”; this is specified by writing two patterns separated by a comma, as above. Patterns can be text matches, as in `/pattern/`, where the current line is checked against the pattern, interpreted as a regular expression; they can also be general expressions, evaluated for every line, and considered to match if their result is non-zero or non-empty.

In AWK, the default action is to print the current line.

Putting all this together, `awk '/pattern/,0'` looks for lines matching `pattern`, and once it finds one, applies the default action to all lines until the `0` condition matches (is non-zero). `awk '/pattern/,""'` would work too.

The [Gawk manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Patterns-and-Actions.html#Patterns-and-Actions) goes into much more detail.

Comment: I was not aware of the range semantics with zero as the end of the range. Thanks!

Comment: @StephenKitt This is great! What if I wanted to print until it matched `0`? Would it be `/pattern/,/0/`? What would the answer look like explicitly writing out the default action?

Comment: @user23146 yes, `/pattern/,/0/` would print until it found a line (record) containing “0”. Writing the snippet in the answer with an explicit action gives `/pattern/,0 { print $0 }`, or equivalently `/pattern/,0 { print }`.

Answer (score 7):

The obligatory `sed` equivalent of @StephenKitt's `awk` one:

```
sed '/pattern/,$!d'
```

`pattern` there is interpreted as a *Basic Regular Expression* like in `grep` (as opposed to *Extended Regular Expression* in `awk`/`egrep`/`grep -E`). Some `sed` implementations have a `-E` (BSD, ast, recent GNU/busybox, soon POSIX) or `-r` (GNU, ssed, busybox, some recent BSD) option to make it *Extended Regular Expressions* instead and some have `-P` (ast) or `-R` (ssed) to make it a perl-like regular expression.

With `perl`:

```
perl -ne 'print if /pattern/ .. undef'
```

Answer (score 4):

with GNU and *BSD grep:

```
grep -A1000000000 pattern file
```

Unless your file has more than 1M lines, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

#### Bash

A bit clunky, but it works.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
found=false
while IFS= read -r; do
    if $found || [[ $REPLY =~ pattern ]]; then
        found=true
        printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
    fi
done
```

This version relies on `cat`, but it's easier to understand.

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
while IFS= read -r; do
    if [[ $REPLY =~ pattern ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "$REPLY"
        break
    fi
done
cat
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a pager such as `less` to view output from the command

```
less +pattern
```

Answer (score 0):

## `awk` for lines after (but not including) the first pattern match

If the line containing the trigger pattern is the equivalent of "CUT HERE", you can omit it from the printed output:

```
echoer | awk 'flag ; /pattern/ { flag=1 }'
```

Each line of input runs through two components in the awk code.  The first component is `flag`, which awk interprets as "print the line if the variable `flag` is nonzero".  Since awk variables are 0 by default, this will initially not print anything.

The second component, `/pattern/ { flag=1 }`, sets the flag to 1 as soon as it detects the pattern, and the flag keeps that value for the rest of the run.

By the time that the pattern is first detected, the opportunity to print that line of input has passed.  Any subsequent lines (including additional lines containing the pattern) will print.