# How to sed chunks text from a stream of files from find

Tags: sed, find, xargs

I have a directory of many `*.org` files. I want to select a section of text out of all these org files. 
There is a `* Learnings` header in the content. I would like to select from the `* Learnings` header to the end of the file.

My current attempt is

```
find ~/org/journal -name "*.org" -type f | xargs sed -n -e '/\*\ Learnings/,$p'
```

This however just outputs one concatenated stream.

Expected output would be a stream of the content after the `* Learnings` header for each file returned from the find

also the solution **does not** have to use `sed`

Comment: What output do you expect/need?

Comment: @choroba added expected output

Answer (score 2):

With the GNU implementation of `sed`, you can use the `-s` aka `--separate` option for each file to be treated separately in that regard.

```
find . -name '*.org' -type f -exec sed -s '/\* Learnings/,$!d' {} +
```

With `awk`:

```
find . -name '*.org' -type f -exec awk '
  FNR == 1 {found = 0}; /\* Learnings/ {found = 1}; found' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

In Perl, you can use [eof](http://p3rl.org/eof) that will be true for each end of file:

```
find . -type f -name '*.org' -exec perl -ne 'print if /\* Learnings/ .. eof' {} +
```

Using the `+` form of `-exec` works similarly to `xargs`: it builds the arguments to the specified command by appending all the found files.

Answer (score 0):

Unless this is some kind of homework ;-), you can use the same trick as [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/509238/308316) with GNU or *BSD grep:

```
grep -hrFA 10000 '* Learnings' directory
```

Replace 10000 with something bigger if your files have more than 10000 lines.

Answer (score 0):

examine it in gnu sed,

```
find ~/org/journal -iname "*.org" -type f -exec sed -nE '/\*\sLearnings/,$ p' '{}' +
```

to really edit and save it, with the origin in a file with .o extension,

```
find ~/org/journal -iname "*.org" -type f -exec sed -i.o -nE '/\*\sLearnings/,$ p' '{}' +
```